# Converting from a for to a while loop in Python

Tags: python

I need the user to input the number of rows and it will print out a this with stars.
I have this done with the for statement:

```
#Number of rows
n = int(input('Enter number of rows: '))
for i in range (n):
    print('*****')
```

But how would I go about doing this with the while , I have this so far but it doesn't work correctly:

```
#Number of rows
n = int(input('Enter number of rows: '))
j = 0
while j != n :
    print('*****')
```

Comment: Add `j += 1` inside your loop.

Comment: This illustrates one reason why `for` loops are generally better- hard to accidentally write an infinite `for` loop

Comment: Figured it out thank you both! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
n = int(input('Enter number of rows: '))
j = 0
while j != n :
    print('*****')
    j += 1
```